# Mysql Error creating Kamailio database

Tags: mysql, macos, kamailio

I have an error when try to run the script for create the mysql database in kamailio (`/usr/local/sbin/kamdbctl create`). The error:

`ERROR 1682 (HY000) at line 1: Native table 
    'performance_schema'.'session_variables' has the wrong structure
    usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
        [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
        [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
        [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
    /usr/local/lib64/kamailio//kamctl/kamdbctl.mysql: line 111: [: =: unary 
    operator expected
    \E[37;33mINFO: creating database kamailio ...
    ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check 
    the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
    syntax to use near '' at line 1`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this error with the kamailio script can be found in this gitlist:
https://github.com/klaussilveira/gitlist/issues/661